# Is there any way to look at and modify the Application Layer Firewall via the command line?

Tags: macos, firewall

We have an issues where an application changed it's service name and UAC prompted users to allow or deny, and a lot of users clicked deny. If users go in to system preferences, security, firewall and then change the rule from deny to allow, it's fine, but at this scale, it's just not happening fast enough for us, and we want to have users report in with this application ASAP.

I'm assuming there is a way. Is there a defaults domain or a plist that can be modified?

I looked [here](http://krypted.com/mac-security/command-line-alf-on-mac-os-x/), but when dumping out the config, I don't see any of the existing rules I see in the GUI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. That link I posted was an older version of OSX. [This article](http://krypted.com/mac-security/command-line-firewall-management-in-os-x-10-10/) had the right version and it works for me!

Thanks!